# The type already contains a definition for 'Zehut'

Tags: c#

The problem exists in my editme.aspx page.

```
Error 1 The type 'editme' already contains a definition for 'Zehut' C:\Documents and Settings\Itay.ITAYB-5A14B8105\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\WebSites\WebSite2\editme.aspx.cs 110 20 C:\...\WebSite2\
Error 3 Ambiguity between 'editme.Zehut' and 'editme.Zehut(object, System.Web.UI.WebControls.ServerValidateEventArgs)' C:\Documents and Settings\Itay.ITAYB-5A14B8105\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\WebSites\WebSite2\editme.aspx.cs 44 13 C:\...\WebSite2\
```

I can't understand where there is a second Zehut method. This is the only zehut method in the whole file.

Here is the code:
http://pastebin.com/xzDcg1RB

It happened just out of the blue. It worked fine for a month or so.

Comment: Can you paste the codebehind file as well?  That error seems to point to you possibly having a method called the same thing as the textbox you're validating.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might have written a `Zehut` method, but there is a `Zehut` textbox in the page (line 70 in the aspx), this is the conflict.